WebRTC: Packets get received, but video is not showing
I have a "mediaserver" built with C++ and libdatachannel to receive video streams via WebRTC. It serves a simple signalling protocol, and the client has to send an offer to receive video, and will then get VP9 packets sent over the peer connection.
Receiving the stream works fine in my C++ client, but I cannot get it to work in the browser, neither Chrome nor Firefox. The below info is all based on Chrome.
When the server is running locally, the browser client seems to connect, but according to chrome://webrtc-internals/ it seems that no packets get actually received, at least there's nothing in the Stats tables section for the succeeded candidate pair.


When the server is running remotely, the browser client seems to connect, and I see that bytes are received:


However, in both cases, no video is showing (the promise returned by play() never resolves) and I can't figure out where exactly the problem is. The JS code attempting the connection is this:
<!doctype html>
<title>test js browser client</title>
<section class="content">

    <title>WebRTC test with WebSocket signalling</title>
    <video id="video-element" muted height="200" width="300"></video>

    <p>Mediaserver IP</p>
    <input type="text" id="ip_input" name="input" required minlength="7" size="10" value="46.4.38.241"/>

    <p>Topic</p>
    <input type="text" id="topic_input" name="input" required minlength="1" size="10" value="foobar"/>

    <input type="button" id="button" value="Start stream" />
    <p>Status: <div id="errmsg"></div></p>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("button").onclick=function() {
            const topic = document.getElementById('topic_input').value;
            const mediaserver_ip = document.getElementById('ip_input').value;
            if (topic == "") {
                return
            }

            const videoElement = document.getElementById('video-element');

            // make a new peer connection
            const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
                // Recommended for libdatachannel
                bundlePolicy: 'max-bundle',
            });

            pc.addTransceiver('video', { direction: 'recvonly' });
            if (!RTCRtpSender.getCapabilities) {
                console.log("RTCRtpSender has no capabilities")
                return
            };

            const { codecs } = RTCRtpSender.getCapabilities('video');
            const [ transceiver ] = pc.getTransceivers();

            const vp9_profile_2 = codecs.find(c => c.mimeType === 'video/VP9' );
            if (vp9_profile_2 && transceiver.setCodecPreferences) {
                transceiver.setCodecPreferences([ vp9_profile_2 ]);
            } else {
                console.log("No vp9 profile or cannot set preferences")
            }
            pc.createOffer({offerToReceiveVideo:1}).then((offer) => {
                console.log("Local offer: ", offer)
                pc.setLocalDescription(offer);

                var websock = new WebSocket("ws://" + mediaserver_ip + ":8080");

                window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                    pc.close();
                    websock.close();
                    return null;
                }

                websock.onopen = function(evt) {
                    websock.send(JSON.stringify({"sdp": pc.localDescription["sdp"], "topic": topic,
                        "direction": "receiver"}));
                }

                websock.onmessage = function(evt) {
                    reply = JSON.parse(evt.data)
                    console.log(`Server reply: ${evt.data}`)
                    const status = reply["ok"]
                    if (status != true) {
                        document.getElementById("topic_input").style.border = "1px solid #FF0000"
                        document.getElementById("errmsg").value = reply["error"]
                        return
                    } else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("topic_input").style.border = "1px solid #00FF00"
                    }
                    console.log("Setting remote response: ", reply["sdp"]);
                    reply.type = "answer"
                    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(reply));
                };


            });

            pc.ontrack = (evt) => {
                const videoElement = document.getElementById('video-element');
                videoElement.srcObject = evt.streams[0];
                videoElement.play();
            };

        };
    </script>
</section>

As an example, the browser's SDP received by the server is
v=0
o=- 8335876533502472473 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=group:LS 0
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7A:E0:F7:6B:15:A7:DE:EA:B6:35:3F:44:DA:F1:F4:7B:CD:D4:24:61:FB:81:4D:D4:4D:5A:CE:E2:AA:3B:C8:28
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=group:LS 0
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:4 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=recvonly
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=setup:actpass
a=ice-ufrag:iIYk
a=ice-pwd:MM67D85LOn4AGaJqrZoJHJlT
a=candidate:37153457 1 udp 2113937151 633dd8b6-dae3-487d-bec3-0e24144442f6.local 61230 typ host generation 0 network-cost 999
a=candidate:3216145886 1 udp 2113939711 bd134863-1992-4778-bd10-6562b4866557.local 49342 typ host generation 0 network-cost 999

and the server's response is
v=0
o=rtc 391121705 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=group:LS 0
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
a=ice-options:ice2,trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 A2:73:8F:40:D0:64:77:8C:D2:56:61:4F:13:44:7A:3F:BC:79:0B:59:5F:72:06:89:E0:57:2D:B0:66:4B:A0:8F
m=video 7141 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98
c=IN IP4 46.4.38.241
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:4 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=sendonly
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=setup:active
a=ice-ufrag:fDod
a=ice-pwd:k0MMaKc0pxVr9rF8lgbO0/
a=candidate:3 1 UDP 2130705919 2a01:4f8:221:3081::2 7141 typ host
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2122317823 46.4.38.241 7141 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2122317567 172.19.0.1 7141 typ host
a=end-of-candidates


My questions are thus:

Why do I not get a displayed video in the browser despite incoming RTP packets? Could this be related to payload types or ssrcs of incoming RTP packets?
Why do I not receive any packets when the server is running on localhost, but do when it is running somewhere in the cloud?


This indicates either SRTP decryption failures or a failure to match the packets to the m-line using the mid extension. The chrome logs will tell you which of these is more likely.

What logs are you referring to? How can I view them?

https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/logging/

At least for this specific case, the answer turned out to be that I was not adding an SSRC on the sender (server) track in this specific code path.
The ssrc should be added to the track by whomever sends stream data as far as I understand, regardless of whether they offer or answer.
Not sure how I would be able to tell this from the SDP or the chrome webrtc logging.

it's also important to set some or all of  media.mediasource.vp9.enabled, media.peerconnection.video.vp9_enabled and media.peerconnection.video.vp9_preferred in Firefox. For safari, I had to first debug via macOS, before it magically started playing.
